# Possible to fix multiple header texts at the top of a website?

Tags: html, javascript, css

I believe I've seen this done before, but I can't remember where.  What I want is to fix text to the top of the screen (like you can do with the nav bar, but I want it to be just a heading text for a section of the site instead of the nav bar), and then when you scroll down to the next section, new heading text bumps it out of the way and stays locked until the next section.

Looking at my design I've uploaded, I'd like "motalife.photography" to be at the top while scrolling through the photography section, and then to get bumped out of the way and have "motalife.design" to be fixed at the top while scrolling through that section.  Is it possible?

[image: sample website design]

Answer (score 1):

You might like to read up on "position: sticky":
https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/position

> A common use for sticky positioning is for the headings in an alphabetized list. The B heading will appear just below the items that begin with A until they are scrolled offscreen. Rather than sliding offscreen with the rest of the content, the B heading will then remain fixed to the top of the viewport until all the B items have scrolled offscreen, at which point it will be covered up by the C heading, and so on.

From what I've read, it was dropped for a while but has recently been revived. So it may not work in all circumstances, and there are various associated issues you'll want to be aware of. I've just tested it on a div in my current project (including -webkit-sticky and -moz-sticky for good measure), and it seemed to work as described (in FF and Chromium on Mint).